# Matrix of objects?

Tags: object, boost, stl, matrix

I would like to create a matrix of objects, and I would also like to access its elements in a "matrix(i,j)" fashion. I first thought of Boost but as far as I understand Boost matrices are composed of fundamental data types such as int or double, and not by other, more complex objects.

I have also thought about using STL; I remember having seen an STL definition of a 2D matrix using vector twice.

Cheers,
Jose

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can use the boost matrix classes for arbitrary types; it's just that a bunch of the numeric algorithms need the elements in the matrix to have numeric-like semantics.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/types_overview.htm and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm

Here's an example:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <string>
int main (int argc, const char * argv [] ) {
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix <std::string> strMatrix (5, 4);
    strMatrix ( 3, 4 ) = std::string ( "Hello!" );
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marshall, it was indeed a semantic problerm. I'm going with Boost for my problem!